# W3Schools Try-it Editor

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

Does anyone know how to get, or where to get, or how to make, or where to find a tutorial, about the [w3schools try it editor](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_basic)?

I need an editor like it, so when typing js/html/css the code be accepted and shown like the tryit editor.

Comment: If you are not quite sure what you are doing, beware making these sorts of things as it opens the doors to a lot of types of attack

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "editor" you are referring to is nothing more but:

```
<form action="<?= $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="POST">
<input type="submit">

<textarea name="code"><?= htmlentities($_POST["code"]) ?></textarea>

<div id="output">
  <?= $_POST["code"] ?>
</div>
```

And the PHP form sending could even be replaced by:

```
<button onclick='$("#output").html( $("textarea#code").value )'>
```

Answer (score 7):

If I understand that correctly, you're looking for a Javascript or PHP editor?

For JS I use [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net),
and for PHP I use [codepad.org](http://codepad.org).

Answer (score 4):

Your question wasn't super clear, but it sounds like you're asking for another tool similar to the [W3Schools Tryit Editor](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_basic).

I use http://jsfiddle.net/, and I love it. It lets you quickly add HTML, JS, and CSS to the editor and get the results. It also lets you save/share your code with others. It's great for mocking up something quick and sending it out to get approved or to get help with syntax.

Comment: but i look for editor that i can use , i want to use it on my own site or smt..